# T-SQL return individual values instead of cumulative value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a 1 table in a db that stored Incoming, Outgoing and Net values for various Account Codes over time. Although there is a date field the sequence of events per Account Code is based on the "Version" number where 0 = original record for each Account Code and it increments by 1 after each change to that Account Code.

The Outgoing and Incoming values are stored in the db as cumulative values rather than the individual transaction value but I am looking for a way to Select * From this table and return the individual amounts as opposed to the cumulative.

Below are test scripts of table and data, and also 2 examples.

If i Select where code = '123' in the test table I currently get this (values are cumulative);

```
+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| Code |    Date    | Version | Incoming| Outgoing| Net |
+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| 123  | 01/01/2018 |       0 |     100 |       0 | 100 |
| 123  | 07/01/2018 |       1 |     150 |       0 | 150 |
| 123  | 09/01/2018 |       2 |     150 |     100 |  50 |
| 123  | 14/01/2018 |       3 |     200 |     100 | 100 |
| 123  | 18/01/2018 |       4 |     200 |     175 |  25 |
| 123  | 23/01/2018 |       5 |     225 |     175 |  50 |
| 123  | 30/01/2018 |       6 |     225 |     225 |   0 |
+------+------------+---------+---------+---------+-----+
```

This is what I would like to see (each individual transaction);

```
+------+------------+---------+----------+----------+------+
| Code |    Date    | Version | Incoming | Outgoing | Net  |
+------+------------+---------+----------+----------+------+
|  123 | 01/01/2018 |       0 |      100 |        0 |  100 |
|  123 | 07/01/2018 |       1 |       50 |        0 |   50 |
|  123 | 09/01/2018 |       2 |        0 |      100 | -100 |
|  123 | 14/01/2018 |       3 |       50 |        0 |   50 |
|  123 | 18/01/2018 |       4 |        0 |       75 |  -75 |
|  123 | 23/01/2018 |       5 |       25 |        0 |   25 |
|  123 | 30/01/2018 |       6 |        0 |       50 |  -50 |
+------+------------+---------+----------+----------+------+
```

If I had the individual transaction values and wanted to report on the cumulative, I would use an OVER PARTITION BY, but is there an opposite to that?
I am not looking to redesign the create table or the process in which it is stored, I am just looking for a way to report on this from our MI environment.

Note: I've added other random Account Codes into this to emphasis how the data is not ordered by Code or Version, but by Date.

thanks in advance for any help.

```
USE [tempdb];

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table1];
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
 [Code] CHAR(3)
,[Date] DATE
,[Version] CHAR(3)
,[Incoming] DECIMAL(20,2)
,[Outgoing] DECIMAL(20,2)
,[Net] DECIMAL(20,2)
);
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1] VALUES
('123','2018-01-01','0','100','0','100'),
('456','2018-01-02','0','50','0','50'),
('789','2018-01-03','0','0','0','0'),
('456','2018-01-04','1','100','0','100'),
('456','2018-01-05','2','150','0','150'),
('789','2018-01-06','1','50','50','0'),
('123','2018-01-07','1','150','0','150'),
('456','2018-01-08','3','200','0','200'),
('123','2018-01-09','2','150','100','50'),
('789','2018-01-10','2','0','0','0'),
('456','2018-01-11','4','225','0','225'),
('789','2018-01-12','3','75','25','50'),
('987','2018-01-13','0','0','50','-50'),
('123','2018-01-14','3','200','100','100'),
('654','2018-01-15','0','100','0','100'),
('456','2018-01-16','5','250','0','250'),
('987','2018-01-17','1','50','50','0'),
('123','2018-01-18','4','200','175','25'),
('789','2018-01-19','4','100','25','75'),
('987','2018-01-20','2','150','125','25'),
('321','2018-01-21','0','100','0','100'),
('654','2018-01-22','1','0','0','0'),
('123','2018-01-23','5','225','175','50'),
('321','2018-01-24','1','100','50','50'),
('789','2018-01-25','5','100','50','50'),
('987','2018-01-26','3','150','150','0'),
('456','2018-01-27','6','250','250','0'),
('456','2018-01-28','7','270','250','20'),
('321','2018-01-29','2','100','100','0'),
('123','2018-01-30','6','225','225','0'),
('987','2018-01-31','4','175','150','25')
;
GO

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
WHERE [Code] = '123'
GO;


USE [tempdb];

IF EXISTS ( SELECT  *
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table1'
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo')
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table1];
GO;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `lag()`:

```
select Evt, Date, Version,
       (Loss - lag(Loss, 1, 0) over (partition by evt order by date)) as incoming,
       (Rec - lag(Rec, 1, 0) over (partition by evt order by date)) as outgoing,
       (Net - lag(Net, 1, 0) over (partition by evt order by date)) as net
from [dbo].[Table1];
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in getting back to you, this worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the instant answer. I have voted up by as I've next to no rep I isn't displaying publicly.

Comment: @ChrisCarroll . . . The OP can accept one answer (regardless of rep) if s/he thinks that answers the question.